# "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop error" despite having a key

Tags: reactjs

I have the following error which I am familiar with :

[image]

However this time I don't understand why it's here.
Here is my code:

`Chat.js`

```js
      ...

      {
        chats.map(chat => (
          <div key={chat._id} id={chat._id}> // <--- line 200
            <input
              checked={
                chat._id === selectedChat?._id
              }
              id="selectedChat"
              name="selectedChat"
              onChange={e => handleSelectChat(e)}
              type="radio"
              value={chat._id}
            />
            <label htmlFor="selectedChat">
              {chat._id}
            </label>
            <button
              onClick={e => handleDeleteChat(e)}
              type="submit"
            >
              X
            </button>
            <br />
          </div>
        ))
      }
```

The `chat._id` exists and work as intended when I inspect the html:
[image]

Note: The screenshot above shows the totality of the ids (2).

[image: Edit smoosh-firefly-b0t8gv]

Comment: Are you sure that every `._id` property is unique?

Comment: Yes, the ones you see in the screenshot are the only 2 that exist

Comment: what happends when you replace chat._id with index?

Comment: @DamianBusz I get the same error

Comment: Thats really weird. Could you create codesandbox for us so we can have reproduction of this issue?

Comment: @DamianBusz I just added a codesandbox

Comment: @DamianBusz I figured out what the problem was

Comment: @HugoBp yeah that was actualy selectedChat.messages.map problem, but nice you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an other `.map()` in the page which had an incorrect key (replacing `msg._id` with `msg.id` fixed it).

The `.map()` of the `messages` is **not** nested in the other `.map()` that was pointed by the error logs at `line 200`, which was confusing and made it much harder to find the origin of the problem.

```js
  {chats.map((chat, index) => (
    <div key={index} id={index}> // <<< Logged error (line 200)
      ...
    </div>
  ))}
  <div style={{background: "lightblue",maxHeight: "250px",overflow: "auto",}}>
    {
      ...
      selectedChat.messages.map(msg => (
        <div key={msg._id} ref={scrollRef}> // <<< Actual error
          ...
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{chats.map((chat, idx) => (
    <div key={idx} id={chat._id}>
      <input
        checked={chat._id === selectedChat?._id}
        id="selectedChat"
        name="selectedChat"
        onChange={(e) => handleSelectChat(e)}
        type="radio"
        value={chat._id}
      />
      <label htmlFor="selectedChat">{chat._id}</label>
      <button onClick={(e) => handleDeleteChat(e)} type="submit">
        X
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>
  ))}
```

Try this, should fix it.

Comment: Using key for the index is a last resort, and defeats the point of the key: "When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort" from [ReactJS.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:~:text=When%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20have%20stable%20IDs%20for%20rendered%20items%2C%20you%20may%20use%20the%20item%20index%20as%20a%20key%20as%20a%20last%20resort)

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the same error. And even if it did, that doesn't address the root of the problem, as I would like not to use the index since I want to be able to dynamically reorder the elements.